# Why not shutdown the s3 client in the code?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am looking for the aws sdk guide documentation.

Below code explains the s3 usage for aws sdk.

In the finally clause, I cannot see the shutdown for the `S3 client`.
It has `shutdown` method for releasing the resource it held.
But the closing the resources cannot be seen in the official document.

My assumption is correct? Or is there any other thing that I have missed?

```
public class GetObject2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String key = "*** Object key ***";

        S3Object fullObject = null, objectPortion = null, headerOverrideObject = null;
        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();

            // Get an object and print its contents.
            System.out.println("Downloading an object");
            fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: " + fullObject.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
            System.out.println("Content: ");
            displayTextInputStream(fullObject.getObjectContent());

            // Get a range of bytes from an object and print the bytes.
            GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withRange(0, 9);
            objectPortion = s3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);
            System.out.println("Printing bytes retrieved.");
            displayTextInputStream(objectPortion.getObjectContent());

            // Get an entire object, overriding the specified response headers, and print the object's content.
            ResponseHeaderOverrides headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides()
                    .withCacheControl("No-cache")
                    .withContentDisposition("attachment; filename=example.txt");
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequestHeaderOverride = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withResponseHeaders(headerOverrides);
            headerOverrideObject = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequestHeaderOverride);
            displayTextInputStream(headerOverrideObject.getObjectContent());
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // To ensure that the network connection doesn't remain open, close any open input streams.
            if (fullObject != null) {
                fullObject.close();
            }
            if (objectPortion != null) {
                objectPortion.close();
            }
            if (headerOverrideObject != null) {
                headerOverrideObject.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void displayTextInputStream(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        // Read the text input stream one line at a time and display each line.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description of `shutdown()` from the [SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#shutdown--) for `AmazonS3` class:

> Shuts down this client object, releasing any resources that might be held open. This is an optional method, and callers are not expected to call it, but can if they want to explicitly release any open resources. Once a client has been shutdown, it should not be used to make any more requests.

Requests to S3 are done via individual REST API calls, so the client doesn't maintain a continuous connection/session as you'd expect from a database client for example. It simply constructs and signs each request using the configuration data provided to it. This is probably why calling the `shutdown` method is not as important for the S3 client.